# Collision function inside a class in ECMAScript6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, collision-detection

I was wondering if anyone could help me, I am trying to create a collision function inside a class Ball. I am stuck as I don't know how to refer to a second ball object inside the Ball class.

Any help would be very appreciated
best regards,
Van

```
class Ball {

  constructor(bX, bY, bRadius, bcolor, dX, dY) {
    this.bX = bX;
    this.bY = bY;
    this.bRadius = bRadius;
    this.bcolor = bcolor;
    this.dX = dX;
    this.dY = dY;
  }

  drawBall() {
    //
  }

  moveBall() {
    //
  }

  bounce() {
    //
  }

  collisions(Ball ball2) { //don't know how to refer to Ball & ball2
    var deltaX = this.bX - ball2.bX;
    var deltaY = this.bY - ball2.bY;
    // ....
    if (sqDistance <= sqRadius) {
      alert("going to hit!");
  }
};
```

Comment: *"don't know how to refer to Ball & ball2"* - `collisions(ball2)` and use `this` as `Ball` instance.

Comment: Uh, apart from that "type declaration" in the parameter your code appears to be working - you use `this` to refer to the one and `ball2` to refer to the other ball?

Comment: You are already doing it... as others have mentioned, apart from a type definition in your method (which JS doesn't support), your code should be working... When you ask a question you have to explain what you expected to happen, what actually happened and any error messages. It's unclear what you're asking here.

Comment: thanks to everyone for responding. Especially to dfsq for responding so quickly, it works fine when I make the suggested change. I am new to javascript and haven't been coding much since my college years... I am playing around with it to learn the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

ES6 does not support type of parameters.

So your code should just omit type
`collisions(ball2) {`

Look at TypeScript when you need strict type check.